# Deleting a folder after a confirmation prompt using a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, rmdir, batch-choice

I am attempting to use a batch file to delete a folder, lets say it's called "D:\Pictures\1\Test". I want cmd to confirm that I want to delete the file before it deletes it using a single press of the "Y" key for yes, or the "N" key for no.

The code below prompts me to give a Y/N input and then closes the cmd window; however, it does not delete the file no matter what I press. If I simply type `rmdir /s /q "D:\Pictures\1\Test"`, it deletes the folder and all containing files without issue, but does not give me a confirmation prompt. Here is my current code. What am I doing wrong?:

```
CHOICE /C YN /M "Are you sure?"
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 close
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 rmdir /s /q "D:\Pictures\1\Test"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `close` command. Use `exit /B` instead.

You could simply remove the `/Q` switch from the `rmdir` command so it prompts you once whether or not to delete the given directory tree.

Comment: Neither of these options worked. Your first solution deleted the folder when I pressed both Y and N. The second one closed the program instantly without giving me time to press anything, and without deleting the folder.

Comment: I accidentally deleted `CHOICE /C YN /M "Are you sure?"`. It works perfectly now. Thanks for you help.